# How would I index each number in this range and search for it with selenium

Tags: python, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

numb = [*range(40, 70, 1)]
print(numb) 

discount2 = driver.find_elements_by_partial_link_text(numb)
```

Im trying to search for everything in the range using discount 2; whenever I run this function it will search it as the whole thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to iterate over the numbers one by one:

```
discount = {} # create empty dict
for number in range(40, 70):
    discount[number] = driver.find_elements_by_partial_link_text(str(number))
```

Now, the results will be stored in the `discount` dict using `number` as the key. I also called `str()` on `number` because you'll be searching strings.

Comment: In this version how would I remove integer `40`, I because I'm searching for specific numbers.

Comment: @Marcus that's a different question entirely. Your OP assumed a range of integers.  If you wanted to just search specific numbers you could add a `list[]` with numbers you want and then replace the `range(40,70)` with the list name instead, in the for loop